# Set Category title as header in list view (TYPO3 tx_news)

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want to add the category title to the list view element, that the category menu sends you to. I'm just not figuring it out...

Here is my code in the fluid template:

```
Templates/News/List.html
<div class="news-list-view">
    <f:if condition="{categories.0.headline}">
        <f:then>
            <h1>{categories.0.headline}</h1>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <h1>News Category</h1>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no field `headline` in a category. Use `title` which should work out well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<f:if condition="{news.0.categories}">
    <f:then>
        <f:for each="{news.0.categories}" as="Category">
           <h1>{Category.title}</h1>
        </f:for>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <h1>News Category</h1>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```